# Rails 3 Validation on Uniqueness - logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following invoice model:

```
validates :po_number, :invoice_number, :invoice_date, :date_received, :state_id, :division_id, :pending_state_id, :approver_username, :approver_email, :presence => true
validates :po_number, :uniqueness => {:scope => :invoice_number}
```

There are times when an invoice record is canceled (state_id = 4), but then needs to be re-created.

Can you help me with how to still validate uniqueness on po_number and invoice_number so the new record can be created even though the same combination exists with a different state_id if it was canceled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described, I believe it may be sufficient to include the `:state_id` in the scope and pass an `:unless` (or `:if`) option to exclude cancelled (or any other states) from the check:

```
validates :po_number, :uniqueness => {
  :scope => [:invoice_number, :state_id], 
  :unless => :cancelled? 
}

# assumes an instance method like
def cancelled?
  state_id == 4
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a custom validator. Something like this might work:

```
validate :unique_po_number
def unique_po_number
  errors.add(:po_number, 'must be unique') if self.class.where('state != 4').where(:po_number => po_number).count > 0
end
```